# Vim command to search a file for a key and add a string after it

Tags: vim

I know how to modify a file if the buffer is open using %s but how do I modify a file without opening it in Vim?

Comment: From _within_ vim or from the system's command line?

Comment: Must it be vim?  Would sed do ?

Comment: Would prefer to do it in vim but I guess I can just echo a system command in my vim plugin. What is the bash command to do this then?

EDIT:Oh it is "sed" add an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: IMHO I think one of the reasons you got a downvote, is because you're asking a question that is linked to vim, but in fact, if you don't open a file in vim, then using vim could be considered not  part of your question. I suggest you re-word you original post (OP) and/or re-tag. Because, in fact, your question is quite interesting. I had never gotten to vim variables (mentioned in one of your answers).

Comment: if you can use sed, `sed -i 's/\(key\)/\1string/' file` would work just fine. (also consider doing a dry run, i.e. without `-i` to check that the command works correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways. Either with `-S` switch to read commands from a file, or `-c` switch to read commands directly from the shell.

An example to add string `four` after the string `third`:

Content of `infile`:

```
one
two
three
five
six
seven
```

You can execute:

```
vim -u NONE -N -c '%s/\(three\)/\1\rfour/ | wq' infile
```

That will yield:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
```

Or use `script.vim` with content:

```
%s/\(three\)/\1\rfour/
wq
```

And run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim infile
```

with same result.

The switch `-u` is to avoid that your `vimrc` file change some options and `-N` is to enter [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) in non-compatible mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external command (`:!`) from within Vim:

```
:! perl -i.backup -pe 's/(PATTERN)/$1whateverafter/g' yoursearchfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is missing the crucial information of **why** would you avoid a buffer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

That said, within Vim, you can use the `readfile()` and `writefile()` functions to read an external file into a Vim variable (without allocating a buffer for it), and write it back. You could then for example `map()` a `substitute()` call over the list of lines, like you would with `:%s` for a buffer.

Depending on your use case, I would also consider using an external tool invoked via `:!` or `system()`; that may perform better and avoid problems with the file's encoding.